# How to compare multiple items of an arraylist into another arraylist at specific position?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

**Background:** there is product listing page and i have to grab all the product name (including out of stock product) and then have to verify that all out of stock product are in the end.

**Problem :** i have navigated all the page and stored the product names in an ArrayList.

lets say `list1` and contents are -

```
[instant bcaa, vegan bcaa, complete bcaa energy™, branched chain amino acid (bcaa) tablets 1000mg, endure™, branched chain amino acids (bcaa), instant leucine, leucine tablets 1000mg, complete intra-workout™, leucine, bcaa jelly mix, complete hydration drink™, informed bcaa™, instant bcaa cocktail bundle]
```

Now i have another list which have only Out Of Stock product

`list2` and contents are -

```
[informed bcaa™, instant bcaa cocktail bundle]
```

I have to make sure whether **list1 has all the list2 items in the end in same sequence**

Comment: assuming the list have no duplicates (each alone): find all elements that are on both (e.g. using `retainAll()`); remove all this elements (`removeAll`)  and add them again at the end (`addAll()`) - eventually using a copy of the first list. Or maybe, stream-like: for every element on list2, if it is also on list1, remove it from list1 and add it to the end of list1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is essentially attempting to validate that a given list `A`, ends with a second list `B`.

You could implement this by determining the length of list `B`, backtracking that many spaces from the end of list `A`, and then doing a pair-wise comparison of both lists:

```
public static boolean listEndsWith(List<?> A, List<?> B) {
    if (B.size() > A.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = A.size() - B.size(), j = 0; i < A.size(); i++, j++) {
        if (!A.get(i).equals(B.get(j))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Java 8+**, you can use `stream().skip()` to skip intial `list1.size() - list2.size()` objects, then compare with `list2`.

```
    if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
        AtomicInteger ordinal = new AtomicInteger(0);
        boolean matched = list1.stream().skip(list1.size() - list2.size())
                .allMatch(item -> item == list2.get(ordinal.getAndIncrement()));

        System.out.println(matched);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate a new list, that is the last n items of list1, where n is the length of list 2. Then compare list 3 to list 1.

The 3rd list can be delivered like this:

```
ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList(list1.subList(list1.size() - list2.size(), list2.size())
```

Comment: Cool idea, though this would throw an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) if `list2` is longer than `list1`, so you'd need to check that first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I like your method better in that regard

Answer (score 1):

To check, that list1 contain list2 from specific position, you can use function:

```
 public static boolean compareArrsFromPosition(List<?> list1, List<?> list2, int fromPosition) {
    if (list1.size()-fromPosition < list2.size()) return false;
    return list1.subList(fromPosition,fromPosition+list2.size()).equals(list2);
}
```

For check of end of list1 you can call like this

```
compareArrsFromPosition(list1, list2, list1.size()-list2.size());
```

Comment: You can do it as a single statement, `return list1.size()-fromPosition >= list2.size() && list1.subList(fromPosition,fromPosition+list2.size()).equals(list2);`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can reverse both of your `List`s (linear time though might require space to store a copy) and match all the elements iterating based on the size of list `B`(assuming it would be of smaller size) as :

```
public static boolean listEndsWith(List<?> A, List<?> B) {
    Collections.reverse(B); // modifies B, so you can choose to clone and reverse
    Collections.reverse(A);
    return IntStream.range(0, B.size())
            .allMatch(i -> A.get(i).equals(B.get(i)));
}
```